# MVC 3 - Entity Framework - Scaffolding - Validation issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, validation, scaffolding

Im developing an MVC 3 application with Entity Framework and Im tring to use Scaffolding.

To solve "Type not mappedd issue" I've done the procedure found [here](http://pinakig.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/mvc-3-scaffolding-issue-with-entity-framework/). Everything now works fine.

Default validation is not working, required field are firing an exception instead of write something on ValidationSummary, so I want to add my custom validations using attributes. 
The problem is that the solution about "type not mapped issue" has added 2 .tt files and a .cs file for each of my entities, these files are recreated each time my model (.edmx) is changed and saved so I cant put my Data Annotation Validator Attributes in those classes and either I cant create a new partial class with some properties because thay are already defined.

How can I do? May I have to move validation client-side using jquery? Or maybe there a workaround to add Data Annotation Validator Attributes to my entities, I prefer this way to have more visibility of my validations.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not used the DbContext generator, but have had similar issues with the POCO Generator. Assuming that the solution is similar:

Modify the T4 template that creates the entity classes to add an extra attribute to the class:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CustomerMetaData))]
```

where "Customer" is the name of the entity.

Then, manually create MetaData classes for each of your entities. You can actually use a T4 template for that, too, if you want, but not have it run all the time.

The Metadata classes look like this...

```
public class CustomerMetaData
{

    [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage="Maximum length is 150 characters.")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="CustomerName is required.")]
    public virtual string CustomerName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public virtual Nullable<int> Type
    {
        get;
        set;

    }

    // ... etc ...
}
```

As you can see, you attach the rules to the MetaData class, thus abstracting it from the generated entity class.

Comment: Can you please give some link about modifying t4 template? This solution sounds me good...

Comment: It's difficult to give you the specifics because I'm using a different T4 template, but there will be one or more lines in the template that generate the source code for the class (search for class or partial class) and insert a line before it: [MetadataType(typeof(<#=code.Escape(entity)#>MetaData))]. I'm assuming (entity) will be the same for your template, but it may not. You should see from the class declaration what variable name is used. T4 templates are quite ASP-like in their construction.

Comment: Thanks, Im inside .tt file and I've almost done! Now I'll create metadata classes to see if everything works

Comment: When it does, the Accept and Up Vote buttons will be waiting... ;-)